# Does empty() utilize isset() in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, php-7

Under the Notes section of http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

It states...

> **Note:**
>
> When using `empty()` on inaccessible object properties, the
>   [`__isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)
>   overloading method will be called, if declared.

**Does that mean:**

```
if( empty( $_REQUEST['data'] ) ){
    return false;
}
```

**is the same as:**

```
if( !isset( $_REQUEST['data'] ) || isset( $_REQUEST['data'] ) && !$_REQUEST['data'] ){
    return false;
}
```

Are the above two statements treated the same?

Comment: Related from the same manual _No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`._  So yes, but you have an extra check and `!$var` should work the same.

Comment: Didn't find anything for PHP7, but for PHP5.6 I found an example: If you have `$gmp = new GMP(0);`, `empty($gmp);` will return false, but `isset($gmp) && !$gmp` will throw a fatal error. Of course this normally does not apply to `$_REQUEST` because the array should only contain strings and arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver My GMP(0) example also creates an unexpected output for the equivalence: https://3v4l.org/95E2O (PHP 5.6).

Comment: @jh1711: I think op is not actually talking about objects but found the snippet about `__isset`.  The snippet I posted is relative to their code example.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, You're right. I just found an example related to isset/empty, where an internal class does not behave as I would expect, or the manual implies. I thought you or OP might find this interesting as well. But I understand if you don't.